# java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable"'

Tags: java

I am getting below stack trace while executing program.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
        at com.test.jie.jverify.JCrypto.ParseSignedData(JCrypto.java:548)
        at com.test.jie.jverify.JVerify.updateSignature(JVerify.java:571)
        at ds_listener.handleRequest(ds_listener.java:58)

        at com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Server.dispatchRequest(JCO.java:7504)
        at com.sap.mw.jco.rfc.MiddlewareRFC$Server.nativeListen(Native Method)
        at com.sap.mw.jco.rfc.MiddlewareRFC$Server.listen(MiddlewareRFC.java:1395)
        at com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Server.listen(JCO.java:7067)
        at com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Server.run(JCO.java:6996)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Below jars are being used

[image]

What I am missing or error about..?

Comment: The tags [sap], [jco] and [sapjco3] are not well choosen here. I do not see what the exception would have to do with SAP or JCo except that you receive some data from SAP. The error is located in your code or the used other libraries starting from `ds_listener.handleRequest(ds_listener.java:58)` upwards in the exception stack.

Comment: Make all your bc*.jar to use same version. I see there are different versions user in your case: 1.39, 1.52, 1.49, 1.39

Comment: did you ever found this issue?